# URL rewriting help

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am stuck in some URL rewriting problem.

```
RewriteRule ^(userratings)/(.*)$ /user_rating.php?userId=$2 [L]
```

This is working for me.

i want to add 3rd variable also. But it might be there or not there also.

```
RewriteRule ^(userratings)/(.*)/(.*)$ /abc.php?userId=$2&product=$3 [L]
```

but the last `/(.*)` can be there or not be there also . So how do i write it for such a condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule will do the job:

```
RewriteRule ^userratings/([^/]+)(/(.*))?$ /abc.php?userId=$1&product=$3 [QSA,L]
```

**Test Examples:**

- `/userratings/12345/hello` will be rewritten into `/abc.php?userId=12345&product=hello`
- `/userratings/12345` will be rewritten into `/abc.php?userId=12345&product=`

This means, that if 3rd parameter in URL path is not present, then value of `product=` will be empty string.